# I m trying to fetch order details from website and getting error "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget'

Tags: flutter

1.getting error on this line as null

```
    enter code here
    return OrderItem(            
               order: model.myOrders[index],
                              onRefresh: refreshMyOrders,
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  )
```

Comment: What is OrderItem? Do you know where the complaining Text widget is?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the indexed order is null and set a default value to protect your code from these types of errors like this:

```
      return OrderItem(            
                        order: model.myOrders[index] ?? 'Default Value',
                        onRefresh: refreshMyOrders,
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              )
```